# My old Windows 7 computer seemingly has no command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd.exe, system32

I'm trying to factory reset my Windows 7 computer so I can use it as a nostalgia machine, but `cmd.exe` in the `%WinDir%\system32` is the Magnifier application (when the computer starts, it opens the Magnifier, not command prompt) and it's as if there is literally no command prompt:

- Any search for `cmd` or `command prompt` results in nothing
- Run → `cmd` doesn't work
- Safe Mode with Command Prompt doesn't work

Is there any way to restore `%WinDir%\system32` or find where the real command prompt is?

Comment: cmd.exe and other files can be changed by malware. Does task manager open? If you have lost/never had the original Windows 7 DVD, you can get it from Microsoft: [Download Windows 7 Disc Images (ISO Files)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows7) (you might need to find that page for your country instead of the UK).

Comment: @Robert I'm puzzled by your comment. They clearly want to keep Windows 7 running. How is installing Windows 10 going to be the answer?

Comment: I would get a bootable windows 7 install medium that works on this computer, boot to the setup screen, then hit SHIFT-F10 to open a command prompt from that location. Then copy the cmd.exe to your  harddisk from that bootable windows 7 setup image to restore the old cmd.exe, reboot and have a working cmd again.

Comment: To fix `%WinDir%` corruption, use PowerShell to issue `sfc /scannow`, but if that doesn't resolve it, you'll need to run the [SUR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/fix-windows-update-errors#resolution-for-windows-7-service-pack-1-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1) tool, reboot, then re-run `sfc /scannow`. This being said, there's no reason to use Windows 7 and doing so is insecure if it's network connected. Windows >8 provides Windows 7 compatibility mode for programs that require it.

Comment: Windows 7 is end-of-life and therefore insecure. It should not be used anymore (at least not in case there is an online connection).

Comment: Windows executables were trafficked, perhaps as an exploit to boot after the password was forgotten. Try running [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) to return these executables.